# Looper Pedal with bypass for specific inputs

Tags: ableton-live, looper-pedals

I'm using my looper pedal for 2 signals inputs.

I would like to have the ability to switch between:
- Loop just the guitar without the vocal.
- Loop both guitar and vocal.

Are there any looper pedals in the market with this ability (preferably with true-bypass)?

If not, then is any tutorial on how it can be done with Ableton Live?

Thank you, 
Regi.

Comment: Wonder whether an A-B-Y switch would do the job . Plug gtr and mic into it, then that into looper, switch to A or B or both. Behringher do one.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I thought about it.
But then i'll need to 2 A-B-Y switches to re-connect with the output.
Feels too complex and not clean solution.

Comment: Gtr and vox are already discrete, Why would you need to have two boxes? If using a single looper pedal, you couldn't re-split recordings. The way to do that is with a double pedal looper - and one AB box.

Comment: I'm not really following. I want to be able to play the guitar and vocal simultaneously, but loop only the guitar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Boss RC-300 supports up to 3 inputs which can be independently controlled. Each channel can be recorded, stopped, started separately, etc., which is then routed to a signal output. The RC-300 is only one example of this type of looper, but in general you will be looking at a higher end product to allow multiple signals/loops to controlled independently.

If you are routing the output signal to a guitar amplifier, you likely won't be happy with the vocal sound. If the output is leading to a mixer for a PA, then a DI box will be necessary between the RC-300 output and the mixer input.

Depending on the level of complexity of what you want to achieve, Ableton Live provides very powerful live performance looping and is widely used by professionals. This solution requires a computer to run the software, and an interface to connect your microphone and instruments. Albeton can then be controlled via a MIDI controller such as a keyboard or sample pad.